# if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am parsing text from an xml file that always reads "There are no new codes." At least once a day this text will change to something different. My goal here is to return the new text when it changes, and do nothing when it reads "There are no new codes.". My problem is that it always returns "There are no new codes."

```
//get source of remote site
$source = file_get_contents('http://someurl.com');

//match strings
preg_match('#<code>(.*?)</code>#', $source, $match);

//if match is equal to "There are no new codes." do nothing else return new match
if ( $match[0] == "There are no new codes." ) {
    /* Do Nothing */;
} else {
    echo $match_one[0];
}
```

Comment: What always returns "There are no new codes."  It sounds like the problem is with someurl.com not returning the correct data.  You should also probably use match[1], and in the else you are using match_one instead of match

Comment: @Matti This is kind of an ignorant thing to say..how do you think DOMDocument and SimpleXML do their parsing?  What is wrong with using PCRE to parse xml in such a simple case as this?

Comment: @tandu - Why recreate something that already works?

Comment: @tandu: Well, I know for certain they're not using regexp.

Comment: Parsing XML with regular expressions invokes the wrath of Zalgo.  D͏̖̮͙͖o̡͈͉ͣ ̩̟̳͗͊̎̽̓̈́̾͜ͅn̳̻̳̲̱̲̍o̮͖̯̳̺͇̠̽͛̓ͦ̓͝tͬ̈ͫ̒͗ͩ҉͔͓͎ ̞̫̯͚̫͕t͖̱̘̺͓͙̯̾̉͒͌ͩ̓̅͜a̢͓̺͎͕̲͒̊u̞̥͚͈̬̙̙̾̕n̘̼͓̗̘ͥ̓̂̈ͧ̉͆t͉̘̂͗ͬ̎ͦ ̧̠ḫ̱͈͎͕͎̈̐͂̅̓ͧ̊ạ̝͋̀̅ṕ̩̯̬̭̬̼̉̂̀̐p̻̖̮͈͔ͫ̍ͣ̾͒̃y̬ͫ̓̔͂ ̤͚͙͛͛ͧ͐̒ͪf̥̖̪͚̑̎̋̋ͤ͗̕u̓͊ͨ̔̚͢ṅ̤̗͉̼̻ͫ̍͗ͨ͞ ͎̯̺̺̺͑ͬZ͉̺̰̖ͭͣa̸̻ͅlͥ̽͑ͯͭ̇ͤ̕ḡ̋̔ͅo̹͖̗ͫ͆͐͆͊ͩͩ̀.̤͕̥̦̼͖̲ͫ͋̈̿̌̂͗͠

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems here.

First, in the regex `#<code>(.*?)</code>#'`, the 0th match (index in the array) is the *entire string*, while the 1st match (index) will be the contents of the parens.  Therefore, use `$match[1]`.

Your second problem is that you're getting XML, but aren't using [any of PHP's XML functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).  You can't safely parse XML with regular expressions.  Try [the DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) on for size.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
$code_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('code');
echo $code_tags->item(0)->textContent;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to look at `$match[1]` not `$match[0]`.  `$match[0]` returns the text matching the full pattern (the code tags and all).