# regular expression to parse in php

Tags: php, regex, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to parse an input value thats hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359527/how-to-parse-an-input-value-thats-hidden)

how do i match the characters in the value using regex? i am using php.

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="c126b4f134cb2c1184c1585fdfa4d1b0013a12f4">
```

i have tried this and it didnt work

```
$code = file_get_contents('http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=522270&boxtag=7xvvk7&sec=form');
preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="key" value="(.*?)" />#', $code, $match);
```

Comment: What patterns have you already tried?

Comment: @canadiancreed preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="key" value="(.*?)" />#', $code, $match);

Comment: [How is this not a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359527/how-to-parse-an-input-value-thats-hidden)?

Comment: [In fact, we've discussed how to properly grab tags and elements using sane methods before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287363/if-else-statement/5287382#5287382).  Please, please don't wake Zalgo.  He doesn't appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the same as in your last question (with DOMDocument)?

If the approach was too complicated, then use phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org). This makes the whole task as simple as:

```
$url = "http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=524970&boxtag=7xpsk7&sec=form";
print qp($url)->find("input[type=hidden]")->attr("value");
```

Comment: i gifured out my issue on that page there is <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cbox.ws/box/jsc.php?v=660"></script> which i believe generates the key for value. so when i try to parse its empty. I var_dump using curl and file get contents and it always shows  the value as empty. What would i do to get the key now?

Comment: @jennifer: You would need magic powers. -- No, I'm not sure. I've glanced over that Javascript file, and it is somewhat obfuscated. If you find the key source, you can probably parse it from there. The first few lines suggest `getcookie("key_"+s_id);` - but there is nothing to read out. Nothing in firebug. Also `javascript:void(alert(document.forms[0].key.value))` reveals no actual value. So I wouldn't really know how to find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$in = '<input type="hidden" name="key" value="c126b4f134cb2c1184c1585fdfa4d1b0013a12f4"> ';

$matchs = array();

preg_match("/<input type=\"(\\w+?)\" name=\"(\\w+?)\" value=\"(\\w+?)\">/", $in, $matchs);
var_dump($matchs);
```

array(4) { [0]=> string(81) "" [1]=> string(6) "hidden" [2]=> string(3) "key" [3]=> string(40) "c126b4f134cb2c1184c1585fdfa4d1b0013a12f4" }

Comment: for $in can i replace that with a url?